# Javascript function not working with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

this is my javascript function to prevent user not to enter alphabets and special characters in the textbox field, it works fine but it is not even accepting numeric.

please note that it is working fine Firefox.

```
function isNumber(event) {
            var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]+$");
            var str = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
            if (regex.test(str)) {
                return true;
            }
            if (window.event) {
                window.event.returnValue = false;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

and this is my textbox

```
<asp:TextBox Width="50px" ID="placesvis" runat="server" onkeypress="isNumber(event);"
```

Comment: "*it works fine but it is not even accepting numeric.*" so, it doesn't work fine?

Comment: it is working fine means that i want to restrict user entering alphabets and special characters that is working but the issue is it is also restricting numeric input.

Comment: Working fine implies everything works. If not everything works, then that's not fine. If somebody is ill and bedridden, you don't describe them as "He is fine. He only can't leave bed and feels awful all the time."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply set the input type to number?

```
<input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```

Answer (score 0):

isNumber is not receives event object, it is receiving textbox as a parameter.

you could try this: `document.getElementById("placesvis").addEventListener('keypress', isNumber);`